Sequelize create() not working for inserting an order, but manual SQL query works
I am trying to create an order using Sequelize in my Node.js app, but I'm encountering issues with both the Order.create() method and a manual INSERT INTO query.
Here is the code I'm using to create an order:
let userId = 71;
let restaurantId = 43;
let status = 'submitted';
let items = '[{"itemName":"meal 1","itemDescription":"meal 1","itemPrice":2}, 
{"itemName":"drink 1","itemDescription":"drink 1","itemPrice":4},{"itemName":"drink 
1","itemDescription":"drink 1","itemPrice":4}]'

let order = await Order.create({
customerId: userId,
restaurantId: restaurantId,
status: status,
items: items,
});

However, this approach doesn’t work, and I am getting no clear error message. I thought a manual SQL query might work, so I tried the following:
const query = `
INSERT INTO orders (customerId, restaurantId, status, items)
VALUES (:customerId, :restaurantId, :status, :items);
`;

await sequelize.query(query, {
replacements: {
customerId: userId,
restaurantId: restaurantId,
status: status,
items: items,
},
type: QueryTypes.INSERT
});

This also doesn't work, and I don't see any results.
Interestingly, when I run the following manual query directly in MySQL Workbench, it works perfectly fine:
INSERT INTO Orders (customerId, restaurantId, status, items)
VALUES (71, 43, 'submitted', '[{"itemName":"meal 1","itemDescription":"meal 
1","itemPrice":2},{"itemName":"drink 1","itemDescription":"drink 1","itemPrice":4}, 
{"itemName":"drink 1","itemDescription":"drink 1","itemPrice":4}]');

here is my Order model in case there is something I am missing:
const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {

customerId:{
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references:{
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'id'
    },
    onDelete:'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
},
restaurantId:{
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references:{
        model: 'Restaurants',
        key: 'id'
    },
    onDelete:'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
},
status:{
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: "pending"

},
items:{
    type: DataTypes.JSON,
    allowNull: false
},

}, { timestamps: true,

});

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Did you try to log the generated SQL query by passing logging: console.log in the firts query?

The issue has been resolved. It was related to the table schema. I had updated the Order model structure and ran the migration files, but for some reason, the migration didn't actually apply any changes, despite indicating that it had. I had to drop the Orders table and recreate it using the updated model definition. After that, everything worked fine! Thank you!

The solution was to drop Orders table and recreate it using the update Order model definition, I have made sure to make and run migration files to prevent this from happening, but it seems I missed a step somewhere, or the migration files simply glitched. the Orders table simply needed to be recreated!
